# C: how to do struct packing and unpacking into char buffer?

Tags: c, char, buffer, datagram, packing

I am trying to pack and unpack gps coordinates into a character buffer:

I have a gpscoords struct as such:

```
typedef struct {
    char north;
    uint16_t lat;
    uint16_t lat_frac;
    char east;
    uint16_t lon;
    uint16_t lon_frac;
} gpscoords;
```

How do I pack and unpack the gpscoords into the buffer pointed to by the buffer variable? I want to convert integers into network order before packing but I'm doing it wrongly below:

```
void pack_gpscoords(gpscoords *pos, char *buffer) {
    pack_gpscoords(pos, &buffer);
    memcpy(buffer, pos, sizeof(pos)+1);
}

void unpack_gpscoords(gpscoords *pos, char *buffer) {
    unpack_gpscoords(pos, &buffer);
    memcpy(pos, buffer, sizeof(buffer)+1);
}
```

Comment: They're both layed out to be infinitely recursive functions, this means that the function keeps on calling itself until the program eventually freezes or you terminate execution.

Comment: Search for "serialization" and use bitshifts/bitops with implementation-independent types. Don't just `memcpy` the data. Note that for GPS, you likely have NEMA, which is an ASCII-format.

Comment: Are you sure you want to unconditionally recurse into your functions? Infinite descent is not usually a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should make the byte buffer `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Here is how you can do this:

```
void pack_gpscoords(gpscoords *pos, unsigned char *buffer) {
    buffer[0] = pos->north;
    buffer[1] = pos->lat >> 8;
    buffer[2] = pos->lat & 255;
    buffer[3] = pps->lat_frac >> 8;
    buffer[4] = pps->lat_frac & 255;
    buffer[5] = pos->east;
    buffer[6] = pos->lon >> 8;
    buffer[7] = pos->lon & 255;
    buffer[8] = pps->lon_frac >> 8;
    buffer[9] = pps->lon_frac & 255;
}

void unpack_gpscoords(gpscoords *pos, const unsigned char *buffer) {
    pos->north = buffer[0];
    pos->lat = (buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[2];
    pos->lat_frac = (buffer[3] << 8) | buffer[4];
    pos->east = buffer[5];
    pos->lon = (buffer[6] << 8) | buffer[7];
    pos->lon_frac = (buffer[8] << 8) | buffer[9];
}
```

Notes:

- the byte oriented packed representation assumes the same order of fields.
- network order means big-endian: the first byte contains the high order 8 bits, the second byte contains the low order 8 bits.

Comment: why are there 10 slots for buffer[]?

Comment: @Iona: Because it takes 10 bytes to store 2 characters and 4 16 bit ints.

Comment: so for latitude -51.533, I want it so that coord.north = 0; coord.lat = 51; and coord.lat_frac = 553;

Comment: for the latitude we have a character north that is non-zero if the angle is positive, and zero if the angle is negative.

Comment: @Iona: You must specify exactly what the byte buffer is supposed to contain.  I assumed it was a direct conversion of the structure members.  If it is different, provide a precise specification.  How many bytes, what do they contain, what representation for integers, what byte order.

Comment: I just want it in network order, that's all :) how may I do that in code? I'm not very good at C :(

Comment: I want buffer[0] -> buffer[5] to contain in network order the gpscoords *pos

Comment: so lat and lat_frac are both unsigned 16bit ints

Comment: @Iona: your specification is imprecise: you want the gpscoords stored on 6 bytes? What format? if `lat` and `lat_frac` are both 16 bits, that's 4 bytes for these 2, longitude uses even more bits than latitude (-180..180), so that would be 8 bytes.